# json rpc client for services module drupal

Tags: json, drupal, rpc, json-rpc, drupal-services

I am trying to create a json rpc client to access drupal services provided by services module for titanium.

```
function connect()
{
  var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

  var url = "http://10.0.2.2/service/services/json";

  loader.open("POST",url);

  loader.onload = function()
  {
    alert(this.responseText);
  };

  loader.send({"method:'system.connect'"});
}
```

This code results saying 'invalid method'.

I think the parsing of the data is not in the correct format.
Please help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this :

```
loader.send({method:'system.connect'});
```

Refer Working with **[JSON Data in Drupal](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Working_with_JSON_Data)** for more details .